# How to compute gradients of a filter's activation of an intermediate layer, with respect to an input image in Tensorflow 2.0?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I'm trying to visualize the kind of images that activate a particular filter of an intermediate layer. For this, I need to compute the gradient of the mean of the activations in that filter, with respect to the input image, and then update the image with gradient ascent.

I'm stuck on how to compute this gradient in Tensorflow 2.0. I tried this; Here, I'm trying to get the output of filter with index `0` in the `block3_conv1` layer:

```
input = tf.convert_to_tensor(np.random.random((1, 150, 150, 3))

activation_model = Model(inputs=model.input,
                         outputs=model.get_layer("block3_conv1").output)

with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    tape.watch(inputs)
    preds = activation_model.predict(inputs)
    loss = np.mean(preds[:,:,:,0]) # defining the mean of all activations as the loss, in the filter with index 0

grads = tape.gradient(tf.convert_to_tensor(loss), inputs)
```

But this is giving me `grads` as `None`. Here's the model summary:

```
Model: "vgg16"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)         [(None, None, None, 3)]   0         
_________________________________________________________________
block1_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, None, None, 64)    1792      
_________________________________________________________________
block1_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, None, None, 64)    36928     
_________________________________________________________________
block1_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, None, None, 64)    0         
_________________________________________________________________
block2_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, None, None, 128)   73856     
_________________________________________________________________
block2_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, None, None, 128)   147584    
_________________________________________________________________
block2_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, None, None, 128)   0         
_________________________________________________________________
block3_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, None, None, 256)   295168    
_________________________________________________________________
block3_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, None, None, 256)   590080    
_________________________________________________________________
block3_conv3 (Conv2D)        (None, None, None, 256)   590080    
_________________________________________________________________
block3_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, None, None, 256)   0         
_________________________________________________________________
block4_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, None, None, 512)   1180160   
_________________________________________________________________
block4_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, None, None, 512)   2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
block4_conv3 (Conv2D)        (None, None, None, 512)   2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
block4_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, None, None, 512)   0         
_________________________________________________________________
block5_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, None, None, 512)   2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
block5_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, None, None, 512)   2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
block5_conv3 (Conv2D)        (None, None, None, 512)   2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
block5_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, None, None, 512)   0         
=================================================================
Total params: 14,714,688
Trainable params: 14,714,688
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just don't use `model.predict`. This returns numpy arrays, and you cannot backpropagate through numpy operations. The below code stays in tensor land by instead using the `call` function of the model.

```
with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    tape.watch(inputs)
    preds = activation_model(inputs)
    loss = tf.reduce_mean(preds[:,:,:,0]) # defining the mean of all activations as the loss, in the filter with index 0

grads = tape.gradient(loss, inputs)
```

Comment: Ah, I see! Thank you so much! :)